# Detect errors on a page loaded using Page.goto

Tags: playwright

I would typically report a failed test when any of the following errors are reported after loading a page:

- missing resources (javascript, stylesheet, ...)
- any javascript exceptions
- any console.error

I was wondering how to detect "errors" on a page that has been loaded using `Page.goto` in Playwright?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to attach to some events and evaluate the incoming data:

- Missing resources: Attach to the [response](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-event-response) event and check the `response.status()` value.
- Javascript exceptions: Attach to the [pageerror](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-event-page-error) event.
- Console error: Attach to the [console](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-event-page-error) event and filter messages where `type()` is `error`.